# Object-C draw text with BORDER on NSImage

Tags: objective-c, border, nsimage

i need to draw text with border on NSImage. I do something like this:

```
[image lockFocus];
[@"Hello" drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint withAttributes:myAttr];
[image unlockFocus];
```

All work, but i need to draw text with white color and with 4 pixels thick black border.
How I can do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  (Have you looked at the various drawing routines available to you?)

Comment: By "border" do you mean a box around the area where the text will be drawn or a stroke on the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a stroke width and color in the attributes, you should get a stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `NSStrokeColorAttributeName` and `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` with negative value.